# Как скопировать файл или папку в буфер обмена и сохранить из него?

Tags: c#

Действительно, как скопировать в буфер обмена и сохранить файл на диск из буфера ?

Answer (score 1):

Копируешь в буфер путь к файлу.

```
File.Copy("Путь из буфера", "Куда копировать")
```

[Практическое руководство. Добавление данных в буфер обмена](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/637ys738.aspx)

[Clipboard - класс](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard(v=vs.90).aspx)

[File - класс](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file.aspx)